# How to create multisite roles with predefined themes

Tags: multisite

I am using the multisite feature to allow users to have there own mini-blog within the main install.

I have managed to get the register user/site page working, but I was wondering if there is a way to setup different roles for the user to choose from when signing up (Artist, Producer, Designer...for example) and assign each account type its own theme.

Comment: Show what you did to set the registration page.